# Can i listen to two sensors in the same service?

Tags: android, service, sensors

I am developing an android app in which i have to listen to both the proximity sensor and the accelerometer sensor. The tricky part is that i have to use it in the same service.

I am aware that i have to register each listener separately in the `onCreate()` method. But i can have only one `onSensorChanged()` method. Right?

Is it possible to differentiate between the listeners in the `onSensorChanged()` method?

Or is there any other way to do this? Or can it be done in the first place?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ofcourse:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        // Accelerometer Sensor
    } else if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY) {
        // Gravity Sensor
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, from the documentation you will see that the `onSensorChanged` method gets passed a parameter:

```
public final void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
```

And the `SensorEvent` has a `Sensor` field named sensor which you can use to differentiate which kind of sensor has a new value